# Blur Every thing When Click Drop Down Menu Appear

Tags: jquery, html, css

When a click drop down menu appear, I want to blur everything on stage, but it is only blur the body!  I have a sentence in white, when it is blur, I still see the color white of the sentence.  that means the blur is underneath the sentence!  How can I get blur on top of everything, but below the drop down menu?

Please give me a hand.  Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="click-nav">
  <ul class="no-js">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="clicker"><img src="img/i-1.png" alt="Icon">Profile</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-2.png" alt="Icon">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-3.png" alt="Icon">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-4.png" alt="Icon">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-5.png" alt="Icon">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-6.png" alt="Icon">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1> This is a sentence in white</h1>
```

CSS

```
body {background-color:#94dcff; color:white}

.click-nav {margin:100px auto;width:200px;}
.click-nav ul {position:relative;font-weight:900;}
.click-nav ul li {position:relative;list-style:none;cursor:pointer;}
.click-nav ul li ul {position:absolute;left:0;right:0;}
.click-nav ul .clicker {position:relative;background:#2284B5;color:#FFF;}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover,.click-nav ul .active {background:#196F9A;}
.click-nav img {position:absolute;top:9px;left:12px;}
.click-nav ul li a {transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;display:block;padding:8px 10px 8px 40px;background:#FFF;color:#333;text-decoration:none;}
.click-nav ul li a:hover {background:#F2F2F2;}

/* Fallbacks */
.click-nav .no-js ul {display:none;}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {display:block;}

.overlay {
    position:absolute;

    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
  $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
  $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
  $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
      $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
      $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
  $('.clicker').click(
            function()
            {
                $('body').toggleClass('overlay');
            }
        );
});
```

Comment: Create an overlay blanket and append it on menu clicked

Comment: Can you direct with more details, please?

Answer (score 0):

Because the (h1) element is a child of the body, it will always be placed before the body. For a quick fix for this particular example, you could add a color attribute to the overlay css class, but that wouldn't be the same as an actual overlay.

To create a dynamically created overlay, using your current setup, you could add a div to the clicked element with the overlay class. Only the overlay css `position` attribute should be changed to `fixed`

```
  $('.clicker').click(
        function()
        {
           var obj = $(this).children('.overlay');              
           if(obj.length===0)
              $('<div/>', { class: 'overlay'}).appendTo($(this));
           else
             obj.remove();

        }
    );
```

[JsBin example](http://jsbin.com/mobefuco/1/edit?css,js,output) (only differences with your own setup are position: fixed and the click function shown above)

NB, there are much better generic solutions available for this, but this is a quick fix using the specific setup of the given scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed according to your direction, it works in a simple page, but when I turn these codings into a busy page having many more children of the body, the blur doesn't show up as expected. I wonder why.

Comment: I got it works now, it is blur everything includes the drop down menu, and the button, too!  I try to apply Z-index on the drop down menu, but it couldn't help to bring it up.  Any idea?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the current situation. Was the problem in the first comment solved by adding a z-index to the overlay css class? Do you happen to have an example html page where the original did not work?